# how to convert the text file into ms word document in php without using COM object

Tags: php, ms-word

[image]
I want to convert the text data file into ms word document using PHP. Here is my code tried for MS-Word conversion, But here problem is margin setting for word document. I need to set the  margin before printing data into it.

```
    $current = file_get_contents("content.txt");        
    header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=sample.doc");
    print $current;
```

Comment: Perhaps using a library like [PHPWord](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/).... but a text file isn't automagically converted to a native format (BIFF or OfficeOpenXML) word file simply by setting the headers to say that it's one

Comment: It  is converting into MS-word file , but problem is margin setting .

Comment: __NO IT ISN'T__ This is the world of real coding, not Hogwarts coding where magic changes things just by waving a piece of wood..... just because MS Word can read a plain text file, doesn't make it anything other than a plain text file

Comment: And a plain text file doesn't have any formatting information like margin settings, that's what the __plain__ part of plain text file means

Comment: Ok, I agree with you.I am copying the content of text file and just put into ms-word document. saving it as .doc format

Comment: I have attached the image of file after conversion,  2 lines of margin  are printing before data is printing, it should be 1 margin line, In actual file only 1 line is there..

Comment: You can't change anything like margins so long as all you're sending is a plain text file; you can only set margins if you're sending a native Word file (either BIFF format or OfficeOpenXML format)

Comment: Any possible solution to remove the 2 lines of that file during .doc conversion?

Comment: I've pointed you to a solution, the [PHPWord library](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/) which lets you define ___real___ Word files, so you can define the margins exactly how you want them

Comment: Ok, Thanks , I will implement that.